# SCTP over UDP - Java implementation

Tags: java, webrtc, sctp

I'm implementing WebRTC on the server-side, in Java within an existing container server. I need a library which will allow [SCTP tunneled via UDP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tsvwg-sctp-udp-encaps-09) and possibly to a much lesser extent TCP. It is my understanding that only WebRTC data channel use SCTP over DTLS over UDP and that the audo / video data will continue to use RTP/SRTP; if I am incorrect on any of this, please correct me.

So far the only library I've found is [here](https://github.com/heliocentric/jsctplib) and it looks incomplete. The [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org) also looked like an option, but they don't have full support for this or the whole of WebRTC as of yet.

[IETF draft - UDP Encapsulation of SCTP Packets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tsvwg-sctp-udp-encaps-09)

[Jitsi - Google summer of code 2014](https://jitsi.org/GSOC/SCTP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many years after posting the original question, I found a solution; I wasn't waiting, I just had not gotten back on this task until I was home during the pandemic; so without further rambling, this is what I used for an implementation at work: https://github.com/pipe/sctp4j
This is an outstanding library and I was able to bend it to fit into my codebase.

Comment: Were you able to use sctp4j to implement SCTP over UDP? Any pointers?

Comment: Yes, its essentially what I posted above. I pulled the source and integrated it in our udp flow; it was fairly easy to do and the unit tests included helped me get an understanding of the source itself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the O'Reilly book on High-Performance Browser Networking [Chapter 18](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch18.html#_secure_communication_with_dtls) you seem to be absolutly right. I'm sorry that I can not help you finding an appropriate implementation, if there is one yet.

Comment: I may end up writing an implementation for us that still love java, but only if I have time. Thanks for the book reference btw.